# How do I amend the list when it seems to be working?

Tags: python

i'm doing my 20 hour coding assessment for my GCSE and i've almost finished my code, there's just a few errors that are happening that's stopping it from being complete.

```
menuItems = [' ', 'Large all day breakfast', 'Small all day breakfast', 'Hot dog', 'Burger', 'Cheese burger', 'Chicken goujons', 'Fries', 'Salad', 'Milkshake', 'Soft drink', 'Still water', 'Sparkling water']
menuPrices = [0.00, 5.50, 3.50, 3.00, 4.00, 4.25, 3.50, 1.75, 2.20, 2.20, 1.30, 0.90, 0.90]

menuStart = True

totalMoney = float(0.0)

tableNumber = 100

def newOrder():
    orderTotal = 0 
    orderWords = 'Order: '
    global totalMoney
    orderItem = 1
    while orderItem != 0:
        orderItem = int(input('Please list the item reference number: '))
        orderTotal = orderTotal + (menuPrices[orderItem])
        totalMoney = totalMoney + (menuPrices[orderItem])
        orderWords = orderWords + ' ' + (menuItems[orderItem])
    else:
        print(orderWords)
        print('Your total is: £', orderTotal)
        menuStart = False

def amendMenu():
    global menuItems
    global menuPrices
    newItem = str(input('What is the name of your new item? '))
    menuItems.append(newItem)
    newPrice = float(input('What is the price of your new item? '))
    menuPrices.append(newPrice)
    print('Menu Items: ', menuItems[1:-1], '\n', 'Menu Prices: ', menuPrices[1:-1])

def deleteMenu():
    global menuItems
    global menuPrices
    deleteNumber = int(input('What is the number of the item you would like to remove? '))
    del menuPrices[deleteNumber]
    del menuItems[deleteNumber]
    print('Menu Items: ', menuItems[1:-1], '\n', 'Menu Prices: ', menuPrices[1:-1])

def runningTotals():
    global totalMoney
    print('The running total is: £' + str(totalMoney))

def displayMenu():
    print("\n Tim's Diner Menu \n Large all day breakfast - £5.50 \n Small all day breakfast - £3.50 \n Hot dog - £3.00 \n Burger - £4.00 \n Cheese burger - £4.25 \n Chicken goujons - £3.50 \n Fries - £1.75 \n Salad - £2.20 \n Milkshake - £2.20 \n Soft drink - £1.30 \n Still water - £0.90 \n Sparkling water - £0.90")

def menu():
    menuChoice = str(input("\n Welcome to Tim's Diner! \n Would you like to make a new order (N),amend the menu (A), delete something from the menu (X), see running totals (T) or display the menu (D)? "))
    if menuChoice == 'N':
        print('You are making a new order.')
        global tableNumber
        tableNumber = int(input('What is the table number? '))
        if tableNumber > 10:
            print('No ball, try again!')
        else:
            newOrder()
    elif menuChoice == 'A':
        amendMenu()
    elif menuChoice == 'X':
        deleteMenu()
    elif menuChoice =='T':
        runningTotals()
    elif menuChoice == 'D':
        displayMenu()
    else:
        print('Invalid choice, please try again.')

while menuStart == True:
    menu()
```

the first is the fact that when i try to run the amend menu function it takes my inputs but doesn't actually amend the list. i thought this was a problem with the global variable definition but this didn't change anything.

the second, less pressing but more confusing, is the fact that when certain combinations of items are listed in the order, the output for total is way off and a very odd decimal:

> Welcome to Tim's Diner! 
>   Would you like to make a new order (N), amend the menu (A), delete something from the menu (X), see running totals (T), display the menu (D) or quit the program (Q)? N
>   You are making a new order.
>   What is the table number? 2
>   Please list the item reference number: 1
>   Please list the item reference number: 2
>   Please list the item reference number: 3
>   Please list the item reference number: 4
>   Please list the item reference number: 11
>   Please list the item reference number: 12
>   Please list the item reference number: 0
>   Order:  Large all day breakfast Small all day breakfast Hot dog Burger Still water Sparkling water
>   Your total is: £ 17.799999999999997

another example:

> You are making a new order.
>   What is the table number? 2
>   Please list the item reference number: 5
>   Please list the item reference number: 6
>   Please list the item reference number: 7
>   Please list the item reference number: 8
>   Please list the item reference number: 9
>   Please list the item reference number: 12
>   Please list the item reference number: 0
>   Order:  Cheese burger Chicken goujons Fries Salad Milkshake Sparkling water
>   Your total is: £ 14.799999999999999

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the second issue is due to floats. I would recommend storing prices in integer cents and do division on display for whole dollars.

Comment: I'd also think about using an OrderedDict for your menu. That way there isn't an abstract connection between two lists.

Comment: Your lists are properly updated - as you could have found out by yourself by inspecting them -, it's just your slicing that hides the first __and last__ items. You want `print('Menu Items: ', menuItems[1:])` instead. But really, "parallel lists" is an antipattern, you want a list of (name, price) tuples instead.

Comment: wrt/ total being "way off for certain combinations of items", no one is going to try and double-check every possible combination until he spots the issue, so you'll have to provide actual examples, with (for each) the expected and actual result. IOW, a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same program. All you have to do is round the variable. For that you do

```
Variable = round(Variable, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txt = "{}.{}  {}  £{:.2f}"
```

Comment: There should be a description of your answer for both the OP and the future readers to describe how it help to the OP and how your code work?